# How to post json object for existing item screen by using rest service, iam getting response from some 3rd party tool

Tags: acumatica

```
string entityAsString = sr.ReadToEnd().ToString().Replace("{0}", Convert.ToString(root.CategoryID.value)).Replace("{1}", root.Name.value);
```

can i post the data like this, is there any other way to post the data to item screen please tell me.

Comment: Good day Deepika T it is hard to find an issue with so little information. Have you looked at the documentation: https://www.acumatica.com/media/2020/02/AcumaticaERP_IntegrationDevelopmentGuide.pdf

Comment: Yes i have looked into this but using the application how to send json object iam not getting

Answer (score 0):

Deepika, Have you looked at the wrapper in github? https://github.com/Acumatica/AcumaticaRESTAPIClientForCSharp
This project does all the heavy lifting interfacing with the api for you. Perhaps, even if you didn't use the project, it would explain how to post the data properly.

Also it is being maintained by Acumatica so its always current.